# RestTemplate POST request urlformencoded gives 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have the following request :

```
String url = "url to oauth_token";

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        String body = "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=123&client_secret=123&"
                + "redirect_uri=https://axyz.com&code=123";

        HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

        Object token = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Object.class);
```

This seems to return 400 (Bad Request). I have also tried its alternatives where body is a `MultiValueMap` but this is what makes the most sense to me. Is there something wrong with the way I am trying the request?

Answer (score 1):

The values of the POST fields should be URL encoded (you can use `URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8")` for each value while concatenating the `body` string). That's why you get 400 error.

You'd better use a more convenient way to create a POST form entity with keys and values, which will URL encode your values automatically:

```
List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "value1"));
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", "https://axyz.com"));
...
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, Consts.UTF_8);
```

Comment: I tried the `URLEncoder.encode` way and that did not seem to work. And for the `better` solution, is there a spring way to achieve the same?

Comment: I showed another way of creating HttpEntity (UrlEncodedFormEntity extends HttpEntity), so you're free to pass it then to restTemplate.exchange method as before.

Comment: @NewUser Your real url isn't `url to oauth_token` right? What is it?

Comment: ofcourse not, its a proper url which goes to one of the 3rd party apps we use